# Disable cellForItemAtIndexPath Refresh on Scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a CollectionView created on iOS.

The collection view is basically custom cells that appear in a collection view.

My collection view works perfectly from a functional perspective.

The method :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Normally runs when each cell is being retrieved in order to get displayed. Which is also working fine. But this method runs and reloads all the cells when I scroll through the collection view.

For example, on first load of the application, this method will run and load all say 30 items in my collection view. Everything runs smoothly and is displayed correctly. But when you scroll up or down the collection view, this method runs again, which causes the devices to refresh. I do not want that to happen. Any advise?

Btw, the reason why I need this to be done is that when my items are loaded in the collection view they are loaded based on a certain instance of a dataset that is later changed in the application, so every time I scroll, I get messed up and unsynchronized results in the cells. I basically just need the collection view to load on startup and stay the way it is.

Comment: cellForItemAtIndexPath called when cell get visible in collection view, do not avoid this, problem is your reuse identifier in collection view, add your code for reference....

Comment: My code is too complex to post here. Basically, I will summarize what I am doing:
Load Database on app initialization. Load Collection View items from the internal database (this runs in cellforitematindexpath). The user then interacts with the cells. For example, the cell is a light switch, which the user can switch on or off, but if he switches it on, it will not update this action in the internal database. The result of this, is that when cellforitematindexpath tries to refresh the cells while you are scrolling, it will reload the old cell state (which is stored in the internal database).

Comment: are you using custom cell ?, can you post your code for cellForItemAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Just make a if condition where you can check if you need to update the cells value or load it from database(make it in your cellforitematindexpath).

Comment: am still facing this issue. Anyone found a solution?